# How to move Index element to end of Singly List while shifting all other elements java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Im trying to move the Index element to the end of the singly list while shifting all other elements so If I had a list of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and I pass the index 2 to it, it would return {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}.

```
public void moveToLast(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if(index<0 || index > size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + index);
  Node ref= first;
  Node otherRef=first;
  for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
      ref=ref.next;
      for(int j=0;j<size()-1;j++){
          if(otherRef.next!=null)
              otherRef=otherRef.next;
      }   
  }
  E temp=ref.data;
  ref.data=otherRef.data;
  otherRef.data=temp;
```

}

This code that I have written only switches the element at index and the last element, returning {1, 2, 5, 4, 3}

Thanks for the help and keep in mind, I am very new to coding, all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the references while looping, not at the end.

This is a small algorithm that saves you the double loop. I implemented it swapping the references, not the `data`, but there's no actual difference in the result. I'm not sure what restrictions you have about one approach or the other, but if you have methods for removing nodes and so on you usually work with references and not values.

I didn't compile it, so please excuse any error, but I think something like this should work:

```
public void moveToLast(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if(index<0 || index > size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + index);
    Node refToMove= first;
    Node previousRef=null;
    for(int i=0;i<index && refToMove!=null;i++){
        previousRef=refToMove;
        refToMove=refToMove.next;
    }
    if(refToMove!=null && previousRef!=null) {
           Node nextRef=refToMove.next;
           while(nextRef!=null) {
               previousRef.next = nextRef;
               Node tempRef = nextRef.next;
               nextRef.next = refToMove;
               refToMove.next = tempRef;
               nextRef = tempRef;
           }
    }
```

}

Comment: You should probably tell the op what they did wrong, or why this one works.

Comment: Thank you for the code, but I implemented it and it did not shift the values correctly and then gave a null pointer exception in another test

Comment: I edited the code, I implemented it thinking of a double linked list and it's not the case, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this also.

```
if(index<0 || index > size())
```

does not catch all bad indexes. If `index == size` shouldn't be allowed as will be out of bounds and also if the index is the last element then you should return as no need to do anything, Perhaps change to

```
if(index<0 || index >= size())
   //throw exception
if( index == (size()-1))
   return
```

Like you say your code only swaps as you find the indexed element end last element and assign them at the end.

What you need to do is find the first then for each set the link to the next element until the end then you set the last element to link the your original index like so

```
public void moveToLast(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if(index<0 || index >= size())
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + index);
    if( index == (size()-1))
       return
    Node currentElement = first;
    Node elementToMove;
    Node nextElement;
    // if first is the one to move
    if(index == 0)
    { 
        elementToMove = first;
        currentElement = first.next;
        first = currentElement
    }
    // Iterate over the list only once
    for(int i = 0; i < size()-2; i++)  // up to the 2nd to last element as the next element is referenced
    {
         nextElement = currentElement.next
         if(i+1 == index) // next element is the one you want to move
         {
              // store reference to the element you want to move
              elementToMove = nextElement;
              // Skip this element and update to the next one
              nextElement = nextElement.next;
         }
         // Update reference
         currentElement.next = nextElement;
         // Move to next element
         currentElement = nextElement
    }
    // Put the one to move on the end
    currentElement.next = elementToMove
}
```

This saves you having to loop twice over your list, I havent checked or complied this so you might need to add null checks in here also, you many also need special consideration if the index entered is 0 i.e. you will need to reset `first`

Comment: this code worked, thank you so much, it explains it very clearly

Comment: if I were to do the exact opposite and move an element to the top would i just set the elementToMove to first at the end?

Comment: To do that you don't need to loop through entire list, so can stop for loop at `i < index` and you wouldnt need to update every reference, so the line `currentElement.next = nextElement;` could be moved into the if statement then outside the loop set `elementToMove.next = first` then 'first = elementToMove'

Comment: You would also possibly need special consideration if you were moving the last element to the front so change the part below the comment if first one moving to be appropriate for the last and change `if (index == size() -1)` to `index == 0`

Comment: should i completely get rid of the first if statement because if the index is 0 then nothing changes?

Comment: just change `if(index == size() -1)` to `if(index == 0)` also it would possibly be more correct to throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: still cant get it to work even with all of your brilliant tips :(

Comment: Glad it helped, you should accept this as the answer to your question to help others that search for this see which was helpful.